# latex in org mode of emacs and regular latex

Tags: xetex, emacs, auctex, org-mode

What is the difference, advantage or disadvantage of using org mode in emacs? If there are advantages, would you like to explain how it is used and what codes goes into using it. I am new (3 days) to emacs and has just basic knowledge of LaTex!
Regards

Comment: With Org mode you can export the same content to many different formats (HTML, LaTeX, odt).  For a basic usage you don't have to know yourself any LaTeX command or HTML tag.  In addition, Org mode can use the powerful [Emacs Calc package](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/index.html), so you can easily typeset an advanced LaTeX spreadsheet containing complicated expressions.  Org mode has also facilities for planning tasks.  You have all this as plain text (really useful if you use a revision control system).  For more information see http://orgmode.org/features.html

Answer (score 3):

Giordano's comment highlights many of the benefits of using org-mode to generate LaTeX documents. The main *disadvantage* of using org-mode, compared to simply writing in LaTeX to begin with, is that it adds a layer of complexity when you want to customize your LaTeX.

In straight LaTeX, you can simply add a new header line, or whichever particular bit of markup you need. In org-mode, you have several options, including specifying header lines in org-mode keyword format, adding in-line LaTeX, or setting LaTeX exporting options via the Emacs customization interface. There's probably nothing you *can't* do from org-mode, but if you're familiar with LaTeX already, it's going to be a little more involved than what you'd do outside of org-mode.

[Zeroth provided a nice summary here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150525/3197)

For what it's worth, I'm switching over to using org-mode for most of my day-to-day LaTeX composition. If I know I'm going to spend a lot of time on the formatting, though, I write in straight LaTeX with AucTex instead.

Comment: Sure, for LaTeX-only and highly-customized documents the org-mode isn't the best option compared to straight LaTeX.